# How are WordPress Page URLs affected by permalink settings?

Tags: permalinks, pages, url-rewriting

I am finding tons of tutorials about the why and how of modifying permalink structure for *posts*, but absolutely nothing about pages.

Right now, my permalink settings are "plain", which uses a query string for everything. This means all pages are `/?page_id=12345`, for example. I have pages organized into a hierarchy, and have slugs defined for all of them; so I obviously want my page URLs to be `/parent_slug/page_slug`.

How are page permalinks affected by WordPress's permalink settings? All of the examples are for posts, and involve posting date and category; neither of which are applicable to pages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pages aren't affected by permalink settings beyond "Pretty Permalinks" being either on or off. Any format other than *Plain* will enable page slug permalinks, [as long as your server is set up to support it](https://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Using_.22Pretty.22_permalinks).